# How to write file in both U mode and w+ mode?

Tags: python, file-io

I hope my code could write text regularly in both MacOS and Windows, so I hope this script have the function of mode U and meanwhile have the function of w+.

What am I supposed to do with the mode argument in file.open()?

Comment: So a mode of `'Uw+'` isn't working for you?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 2):

Writing in universal newline mode isn't supported. From [the PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/):

> There is no special support for output to file with a different
>       newline convention, and so mode "wU" is also illegal.

and

> There is no output implementation of universal newlines, Python
>       programs are expected to handle this by themselves or write files
>       with platform-local convention otherwise.  The reason for this is
>       that input is the difficult case, outputting different newlines to
>       a file is already easy enough in Python.

This is actually hinted at by the error returned when you try `Uw+`:

```
ValueError: universal newline mode can only be used with modes starting with 'r'
```

Note that `Ur+` doesn't fail, but it also doesn't do any substitution on writing; I can do `f.write('test\r\n')` on my Mac (OS X uses Unix newlines), and a Windows newline appears in my file.

**edit**: It appears that Python [actually offers platform-specific newline output by default anyway](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open), as long as you leave the `b` off.

> ...The default is to use text mode, which may convert '\n' characters to a platform-specific representation on writing and back on reading.